# Separate url in autocomplete menu

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have an autocomplete jQuery menu, that output the name of all the users I have, from a MySQL database. I'm trying to link each selection to the proper profile. For that, the URL is something like: /profile.php?id=341, 341 that stands for the ID of the user selected.

The only problem, is that when I try to put the ID of a given user, ALL the ID of ALL the user are shown in the URL... and I want only the ID of the selected user!

I have tried with PHP, but I don't know what to add to the following line to make it work.

```
$req = mysql_query("select id, Username, EmailAddress from ***");
```

Should it be something like WHERE Username='username'....? Finally, I know that I should maybe try something else, without PHP, but I just want to test it that way! Thanks!

```
<input type="text" name="course" id="course" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

$("#course").autocomplete("/test/test2.php", {
        selectFirst: false,
        formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
            //make the suggestion look nice
            return "<font color='#3399CC'>" + value.split("::")[0] + "</font>";
        },
        formatResult: function(data,value) {
            //only show the suggestions and not the URLs in the list
            return value.split("::")[0];
        }
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        //redirect to the URL in the string
    var pieces = formatted.split("::");
        window.location.href = '/profile.php?id='+

<?php
mysql_connect ("***", "***","***")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("***");
$req = mysql_query("select id, Username, EmailAddress from ***");


while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))

{
   echo $dnn['id']; 
 }
?>


;

  console.log(data);
  console.log(formatted);

    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: What if the username is `<script>alert('xss');</script>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL query is true to every user in the database, so it returns all the users. If you want to go to "foo"'s profile, you need to tell the database to fetch "foo"'s id only. A unique row that the user has maybe there email and must be their username.

I assume you have an array in javascript which contains selected users:

```
var users = new Array("Daniel","Amy","Sandy");
```

then you need to use ajax to communicate to php:

```
<script>
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;    
    }
}//This can become an external file to link
</script>
```

so then you can post data to php:

```
<script>
var returnedStr = "";
function searchuser(){ //use searchuser function on a button to call
    var usersStr = users.toString(); //the string that contain the users separated by ","
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "thisurl.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
        if(ajax.responseText == "fail"){ //i didn't include this in php, but you can add it yourself if you can't fetch from mysql
            echo "Failed";
        } else {
    returnedStr = ajax.responseText;// when php echos
        }
    }
}
ajax.send("u="+usersStr);
}
</script>
```

then your php will need to handle the string:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
    $returnArr = array();
    $returnStr = "";
    $processedArr = explode(',', $_POST['u']); //Here the posted data will turn into an array
    $lengthArr = count($processedArr);
    for ($i=0; $i<=$lengthArr; $i++)
    {
        $req = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM xxx WHERE Username='$processedArr[$i]' LIMIT 1");
        while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))

        {
            array_push($returnArr, $dnn['id']);
        } 
    }
    $returnStr = implode(",",$returnArr);
    echo ($returnStr);
}
?>
```

Now in Javascript `returnedStr` will hopefully be `1,2,3` or something like that.
**Please comment if this doesn't work!**

Comment: I don't get it for the "clue to query in the first place"?

Comment: I meant if you want to go to "foo"'s profile, you need to tell the database to select "foo"'s id only.

Comment: ok, but if the user select a given name in the autocomplete list, how can I tell the database who to select?

Comment: Is it only one to select?

Comment: I think you need to get the value of the auto complete list and name it $u.

Comment: but the value of the auto complete list is in javascript

Comment: you put the javascript in the end of body or in head but add document ready, the php you put in anywhere, but preferably before <DOCTYPE>.

Comment: Useless code should be deleted and useful code should remains, I am not sure the behind-the-scene of your site, so I'm not sure. The script here work alone though

Comment: I have no idea where to put all this code... can I send you a gist of my code, to help me?

Comment: you mean my email? daniel.2345@hotmail.com

Comment: I now have https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5f7e4e934788e04531d5. It rederict the user, but the ID dosen't appear in the URL, so it's not the page of the selected user...

Comment: Can you put the auto complete list selected user into a array variable?

Comment: but i'm not sure how your code works. if you can't get a variable from the list to process with, the script won't work. Or you can ask another question on stackoverflow